# How to customize message in Newsletter subscribe if user already subscribed

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, newsletter, messages

I want to change newsletter subscribe message for users who are already subscribed with that email. By default it show the same message as user gets first time for subscription success.

> Thank you for your subscription.

Kindy guid me from where i can customize it. I am using magento(2.1.8) version.

Answer (score 0):

In Newer version of Magento2, it has been resolved. but in your Magento version You need to overwrite controller `"vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php"`

and put below code just after line 122 `$this->validateEmailAvailable($email);`

```
$subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
 if ($subscriber->getId()
       && $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED
 ) {
      throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        __('This email address is already subscribed.')
                    );
  }
```

to know about how to overwrite controller in Magento2, you can take reference of this [link](https://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/).